# How do I specify the sorting field and direction in a linq query at runtime?

Tags: .net, linq

Lets suppose that I have the following simple query

```
var q = 
    from p in products
    orderby p.ProductName descending
    select p;
```

What would be the simplest and most straightforward way to specify the sort field and direction at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used the dynamic linq library before to do this.  [Here's a link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) to Scott Guthrie's blog where he describes it.

Basically you could alter the above query to look like this:

```
var q = db.Products
        .OrderBy("ProductName Descending")
```

Comment: It worked! Kind of reminds me of SubSonic. What I don't like about it is that it only extends IQueryable so I in order to use it I will have to run .AsQueryable() on my collections.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with a switch statement. Here is a snippet, where I am going in ascending direction. In my url I passed in a parameter to determine the direction, and what to sort by.

```
if (sortDirection == "asc")
{
    switch (sortCol)
    {
        case 1:
            q = from f in q
                orderby f.Id ascending
                select f;
```

q is obviously the result of the original LINQ select.